# Event Date Stamps Messed up?

Tags: civievent

I have been using events for a while and this just started happening - not sure if it is related to moving from one host to another since everything is functioning as expected.
When I select a template or edit an event, the date/time stamps change to 2 boxes with the calendar icon in one, but not usable.
So I added some events without a template and get the single box with a selectable date, but they don't show on my calendar now and when I select Events, Show Events Calendar it returns to the Civicrm admin front page.  Any suggestions on how to resolve??  I am on 4.7.18 and was going to upgrade to 4.7.23 but am hesitant with this error.  I did do the upgrade on my test environment and when I saw this error in production, I went back to the upgraded test environment and the issue is there too.
[image: Double date entry fields]

Comment: I should note, the Show Events Calendar was left over from an old extension - that should be ignored.  I also have a list of custom fields that should be there when adding a new event and they are not showing up anymore.  Something is seriously off here.

Comment: Could you say what CMS you are using and the version of PHP on your server(s).  Has there been a change in PHP when changing hosts?

Comment: Wordpress.  On the server it was php 5.7, dropped it back to match my dev env (5.6) but both were experiencing the same issue.  The php version did change, but is now back to original.  Perhaps I need to go through each plugin on Wordpress to see if one of them is the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this issue was quite obscure but I went through my wordpress plugins one at a time, deactivated and tested and this one: "Social Icons Widget by WPZOOM" was at fault!  Once I deactivated that plugin, events started to work correctly again.  This plugin was part of a recent site update on our test, it apparently passed all the tests and was promoted to our production system.  Time to check the testing checklist again.

Comment: if you accept your own answer then it keeps SE happier ;-)